# Autoclicker code on specific location using java script / tamper monkey

Tags: javascript, browser, automation, coordinates, tampermonkey

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function performClick() {
       
        var x = 100; 
        var y = 100;

        document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
    }

    
    setInterval(performClick, 65000);
})();
```

I want this code to click every min on specific coordinates in browser, and it doesn't work.

Comment: The code looks correct, please check the url part of tampermonkey configuration!

Comment: May not work with frameworks (ex. jQuery) - probably kind of event or framework's click method may work better, but hard to guess. Some other use virtual DOM, multiple sets of same elements, etc.